# Rows to take up the entire screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-button

I have one big LinearLayout(vertical)(outer table) and three small linear layouts(horizontal)(one for each row). I want the linearlayouts inside to take up the entire space. Currently they take up only the required space. 
Here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background">


<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/Tag"
                 android:onClick="tagKillHandle"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/seekills" 
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                 android:onClick="seeKillsHandle" 
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>       
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/track"
                 android:onClick="trackMeHandle"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/taste"
                 android:onClick="tasteHandle"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>           
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/calls"
                 android:onClick="duckCallsHandle"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/faq"
                 android:onClick="faqHandle"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>           
</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

I want the rows to take up the entire screen. How can I do this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
android:layout_weight="1.0"
```

in each of the three inner layouts.

Comment: awesome. thank you. can you also tell me how to fix the width. now they are taking only as much as they need.

Comment: if you want the width of each element to be equal in each row then put android:layout_weight="1.0" in each of the imagebutton

Comment: got it. added layout_width = 0.5 to each of the buttons.

Comment: good.. you can accept the answer by clicking on the tick left of the answer.